# Fill groove in MDF door

Tags: doors, painting, mdf, wood-filler

I'm painting some MDF doors, and noticed that someone appears to have run a stanley knife over one of them, perhaps whilst removing them from their packing.

I've sanded the area back as much as I can, but the groove isn't completely gone. What should I use to fill the remaining void?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on size. For significant blems, I'd try wood putty, handling it as if it were joint compound. If that didn't work, I might just give up and actually use joint compound...

However, remember that for small nichs and scratches paint itself can fill small irregularities, especially if you scuff-sand between coats or otherwise actively level the surface.